# Using User defined types in DB2 and using the type in a function

Tags: oracle, migration, db2, db2-luw

I am migrating my database from ORACLE to DB2, While doing the migrations I have come across a situation related to User defined types. As I have been working with DB2 recently, I have been through the SQL standards and have been successful in migrating most of the stuffs.

I am kind of stuck with this UDT and tried with few of the suggestion by some DB experts here, but the thing I am trying to achieve isnt working well.

I have created the below UDT and created another UDT as table and been trying to use in a function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "XYZ" AS OBJECT (
   aa           VARCHAR2(30),
   bb   NUMBER (18),
   cc     NUMBER (30, 12),
   count      NUMBER (18),
   value_1             NUMBER (18),
   value_2             NUMBER (18),
   value_3             NUMBER (18),
   display_1           VARCHAR2 (256),
   display_2           VARCHAR2 (256),
   display_3           VARCHAR2 (256),
   status              NUMBER (1)
)
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "XYZ_TBL" AS TABLE OF XYZ;
```

As I have read that If we create a UDT in DB2, DB2 automatically creates a function of the above XYZ without parameters I believe. And to use the UDT, we have to create a function calling the constructor. I created a function with a same name XYZ referencing the UDT.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XYZ(
   aa                  VARCHAR2,
   bb                  NUMBER,
   cc                  NUMBER,
   count               NUMBER,
   value_1             NUMBER,
   value_2             NUMBER,
   value_3             NUMBER,
   display_1           VARCHAR2,
   display_2           VARCHAR2,
   display_3           VARCHAR2,
   status              NUMBER
)
return XYZ
IS
rec      xyz := xyz(cast(null as varchar), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as varchar), cast(null as varchar), cast(NULL as varchar),cast(null as decimal));
BEGIN
    RETURN rec;
END;
```

Every thing got compiled perfectly . And I am calling this function in a package as

```
FUNCTION get_combinations(aa        VARCHAR2, bb     VARCHAR2,
                              cc  VARCHAR,  dd NUMBER,
                              prefix_1          VARCHAR2, prefix_2       VARCHAR2,
                              prefix_3          VARCHAR2, filter_1       NUMBER,
                              filter_2          NUMBER,   filter_3       NUMBER)
             RETURN xyz_tbl PIPELINED
    IS
        rec      xyz := xyz(cast(null as varchar), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as decimal), cast(null as varchar), cast(null as varchar), cast(NULL as varchar),cast(null as decimal));
        cur      sys_refcursor;
        ccyCol   VARCHAR(64);
        txQuery  VARCHAR(4000);

\\and doing further stuffs
```

I am using the function to pass the values from different set of tables and building a dynamic select query for further processing.

When I am calling the function in one of the stored procedure, It gives me below error

```
SQL0724N The activation of "XYZ" of type "FUNCTION " would exceed the maximum level of indirect SQL cascading.
```

and when I try to use the UDT XYZ directly into the package without creating any caller for it, the package is not able to locate XYZ and doesn't compile.

So, is there any administrator level configuration change required to make it work? Or are there any such limitations in DB2 regarding usage of User defined Types? Or, Is there any other correct way to use the structured types?

Comment: I tried creating your scenario, but I get an `SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "XYZ" of type "FUNCTION" ...` in `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XYZ(...)`. Can you recreate the scenario with an empty database and what you posted?

Comment: You need to create the Type first and then the function calling the type. `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "XYZ" AS OBJECT (
   aa           VARCHAR2(30),
   bb   NUMBER (18),
   cc     NUMBER (30, 12),
   count      NUMBER (18),
   value_1             NUMBER (18),
   value_2             NUMBER (18),
   value_3             NUMBER (18),
   display_1           VARCHAR2 (256),
   display_2           VARCHAR2 (256),
   display_3           VARCHAR2 (256),
   status              NUMBER (1)
)
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "XYZ_TBL" AS TABLE OF XYZ;`

Comment: I did create the type first, but get the error when trying to create the function.

Comment: I created a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=29f81ffeff17f3a5482a97b11642956e . Can you adjust it so that the function compiles?

Comment: I tried, but  strange, its not compiling on the fiddle, but the same is getting compiled without any error or warning on my DB2 through Dbeaver.

Comment: Can you create an empty database so that no db-objects exist? You may have something in your DB that you (and us) are unaware of, that makes it work.